# Getting Error trying to install MySQL-python on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip, mysql-python

Im getting an error **clang: error: unknown argument: '-fabi-version=2'**
when I try to install mysql-python with pip.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Haruan:MySQL-python-1.2.5 haruan$ sudo -E pip install MySQL-python
The directory '/Users/haruan/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/haruan/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 110kB 311kB/s 
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/sh/gl953xl12p3fl1k0lkw10_k00000gn/T/pip-build-ZBmISy/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sh/gl953xl12p3fl1k0lkw10_k00000gn/T/pip-5RkJ0a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7
    clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -arch x86_64 -g -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-fabi-version=2'
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/sh/gl953xl12p3fl1k0lkw10_k00000gn/T/pip-build-ZBmISy/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/sh/gl953xl12p3fl1k0lkw10_k00000gn/T/pip-5RkJ0a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sh/gl953xl12p3fl1k0lkw10_k00000gn/T/pip-build-ZBmISy/MySQL-python
```

I already used:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export ARCHFLAGS='-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'
```

and

```
sudo -E ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install mysql-python

sudo -E ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip mysql-python
```

the problem persists.

My Xcode is Version 6.4 (6E35b)
and I'm with Mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else runs into this and for whatever reason prefers not to solve it by changing to a different MySQL installation, there's a relatively easy workaround. I ran into this issue trying to compile mysqlclient against the MySQL package included in version 5.5 of the Bitnami MAMP stack. You just need to tweak the installation so the offending parameter is not passed to the compiler, as follows:

1. Download the package from [GitHub](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python)
2. Open the setup_posix.py file
3. After the `extra_compile_args` variable is initialized (lines 58-59 in the current version), add the following line of code: `extra_compile_args.pop(extra_compile_args.index('-fabi-version=2'))`
4. In the package directory, run `python setup.py install`

Worked for me.

Comment: My Python version:2.7.10, when I use  python setup,py install          # error info:You shouldn't be running this directly; it is used by setup.py.%

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, i had XAMPP installed, and the mysql at XAMPP used that flag.
I uninstalled XAMPP and installed mysql through Homebrew, and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with Softaculous AMPPS.
based on the response above from Max and I was able to figure out how to work around the issue.

simply remove the "-fabi-version=2" flag from "cflags" (line: 122 in my case)